# How can I enable retweet email notifications for all retweets and not just from the users I'm following?

Tags: twitter

For a few months now, Twitter has had an option to be able to receive email notifications whenever you're retweeted. However, this only seems to work if you're following the user who has retweeted you. Is there any way to enable this email notification for each and every retweet?

Twitter's web app only shows you an accurate count of retweets till it reaches 100. After that, it just says "100+" and never shows you a complete list of users who have retweeted you. If emails are received for each retweet, an app can be made to collect all that data and show a better count.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter can now send emails when your tweets are marked as favorites/retweeted by anyone. Just change the "Email me when..." to "By anyone".

[image]